# How to prevent GUI from locking up during operation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, async-await

Here is my code:

```
private void RunCoinFlip()
{
    ToggleControlsUsability();

    Task task = new Task(CoinFlippingAnimation);
    task.Start();
    task.Wait();

    ToggleControlsUsability();

    flipOutcome = picCoin.Image == coinSideImages[0] ? CoinSides.Heads : CoinSides.Tails;
    lblResult.Text = userGuess == flipOutcome ? "Congrats you won!" : "Too bad you lost.";
}

private void ToggleControlsUsability()
{
    btnHeads.Enabled = !btnHeads.Enabled;
    btnTails.Enabled = !btnTails.Enabled;
}

private void CoinFlippingAnimation()
{
    Random rng = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        int side = rng.Next(0, coinSideImages.Length);
        picCoin.Image = coinSideImages[side];

        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Basically, the buttons should be frozen during the operation and be unfrozen afterwards, and the coin flipping animation flips the coin. Unfortunately, the GUI is locked up during the animation so you can't move the window or resize.

I've been reading about async and await but I'm not sure if that applies here or how to add it. The different results I try always lead to either blocking, instant unfreezing of controls, or cross-thread execution errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for another thread here, since the time is all being spent in `Thread.Sleep` and not the random number generation. So, a simple `async` solution would be:

```
private async Task RunCoinFlipAsync()
{
  ToggleControlsUsability();

  await CoinFlippingAnimationAsync();

  ToggleControlsUsability();

  flipOutcome = picCoin.Image == coinSideImages[0] ? CoinSides.Heads : CoinSides.Tails;
  lblResult.Text = userGuess == flipOutcome ? "Congrats you won!" : "Too bad you lost.";
}

private async Task CoinFlippingAnimationAsync()
{
  Random rng = new Random();

  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
  {
    int side = rng.Next(0, coinSideImages.Length);
    picCoin.Image = coinSideImages[side];

    await Task.Delay(100);
  }
}
```